# JQuery Selector not Selecting List Items in EmberJS View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am creating an unordered list in an Ember.js view by using the `each` helper. I also have some Javascript that runs on the `didInsertElement` hook, which selects each list item. However, that selector fails to select any elements if I generate the list using the `each` helper. Any thoughts on how to get results from the selector?

relevant view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="slider">
    <ul>
        {{#each slide in controller}}
            <li><img src="./resource/locations/1/test.jpg"></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <br>
</script>
```

relevant JS:

```
App.SliderView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "slider",
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        var items = $(">ul>li", self.$());

        //...
    }
});
```

**Update:**

I believe the problem arises because I am loading the models that populate my controller asynchronously. Is there any way to listen to the event that occurs when the model is first populated?

My Model Code:

```
App.Location = DS.Model.extend({
    thenSlider: DS.hasMany("slide", {async: true})
});

App.Slide = DS.Model.extend({
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me, you're probably facing a problem where your data is populating after `didInsertElement` has fired.  `didInsertElement` only fires when `Slider` has been inserted initially, not necessarily when the elements inside of it are inserted/modified.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/liluxece/1/edit

Since it's async, I'd use `render` and hook it up to another view, that way you can use `didInsertElement` on a case by case situation for each item.

```
{{render 'template' context}}
```

Here's an example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/liluxece/5/edit

Comment: but when I call `console.log` on `items` after it has rendered, the selector does return those `li`s in your example.

Comment: You'll need to give more info on your particular example, even if you log in `didInsertElement` in my example it shows them.

Comment: ok, I think I isolated the problem further--see my update above.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the jquery, it's possible we could solve it easier and not have problems as you add or remove items.

Comment: I'm building an image gallery, which involves programmatically adding CSS classes after the `li`s have been loaded. I want to select them so I can add those classes and listen to events on them. Is there any way to listen to when the `each` tag has finished populating the view?

Comment: I tossed up an example with render, it will give you a view for each item, which won't fire until the li is inserted into the ul, and then you'll be guaranteed to have access to that li.

Comment: All right--I fixed it without too much hassle by listening to DOM changes in the list and automatically re-selecting all list items in the list every time they change. Thanks for all your help!